# Populate list in form from a table (Entity Framework) then use in other places in the form code

Tags: c#, winforms

New C# and Entity Framework user. I want to put the results of a table into a C# list. I want to reference this list in multiple form events. I will cycle through the list from beginning to end throughout the life of the form.

Currently, I have this code (snippet):

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    private readonly admEntities _admEntities = new admEntities();
    
    public FrmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var exhibitor = _admEntities.Exhibitors.ToList();

        // Put the first value in a text box - this works
        txtCurrentSaleOrder.Text = exhibitor.First().SaleOrder.ToString();
    }
}
```

I was hoping to use the exhibitor variable elsewhere on other events. However, I am unable to reference it.

I have not been successful in my searching and coding attempts to resolve this problem so far. Any pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

One thing I tried was to put this code in a class above `FrmMain()`. That also failed. Probably due to not fully understanding classes yet.

Comment: Have you tried making exhibitor a field/property of the class?

Comment: `I tried was to put this code in a class above FrmMain(). That also failed.`  What failed?

Comment: You need to make your question very clear by providing more information and if you have images to also use in illustration your issue.

Comment: @MarkAdesinaOmoniyi We don't need images unless this is a graphical question.  It's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make `exhibitor` a field, which is a fancy way of saying declare it outside of a method, inside of your class. Here is an example where exhibitor can be accessed from anywhere else in the class.

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    private readonly admEntities _admEntities = new admEntities();
    
    //It's unclear what exhibitor is in your question, so I'm using generic code that will allow it to work regardless.
    private Type exhibitorType = typeof(admEntities.Exhibitors);
    private List<exhibitorType> exhibitor = new List<exhibitorType>();
    
    public FrmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Can reference here
        exhibitor = _admEntities.Exhibitors.ToList();
        
        txtCurrentSaleOrder.Text = exhibitor.First().SaleOrder.ToString();
    }

    private void AnotherMethod()
    {
        //Can reference exhibitor here too.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Josh, I had tried something similar to your example above and get a message that Exhibitor does not exist in the type admEntities. To clarify = admEntities is the Entity Framework model. Exhibitors is one of the tables in the model. SaleOrder in the formload code is a field in the Exhibitors table. My initial expectation is that I could reference the exhibitor list variable I have in the frmMain_Load elsewhere in another method. However, that did not work.

Comment: Ok - I was able to work through my errors and your example above to get a working solution. Thank you very much for the guidance.